# How to match Underscore in String - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

if column value is `2_apples` or `final_chapter` how do i match a value that contains an underscore `"_"` ?

I've tried with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM `items` WHERE brand like '%\\_'
SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM `items` WHERE brand like '_'
SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM `items` WHERE brand like '%_%'
SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM `items` WHERE brand like LIKE '\_'
```

It either shows all results or none. Any suggestions?

Comment: The third one should work fine.

Comment: i did but it fetches Sony `Playstation`
`Micronet`
`Playstation 4`
`Gaems`
`Sony VR` but not `e_gold`

Comment: In addition to the answer below and the duplicate link, you could also use `REGEXP` with underscore directly, without the need to escape: `WHERE brand REGEXP '_'`

Comment: @enucar - The third one should match any character

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try

```
WHERE brand LIKE '%\_%'
```

The underscore is a wildcard for a single character whereas the % is a wildcard for multiple (or none) characters. Put a backslash in front to escape them.

If you don't like escaping things, because it's ugly or scary, then an alternative would be to use the `REGEXP` operator with underscore directly:

```
WHERE brand REGEXP '_'
```